# If $x$ belongs $V$ then $Tw = w$ if and only if $x = v + k$ with $k$ in $\operatorname{ker}(T)$

Tags: linear-algebra, transformation

Let $F$ a field, $V$ and $W$ vector spaces, $T$ a linear transformation from $V$ to $W$, if $w$ belongs $W$ and $v$ in $V$ such that $Tv = w$, if $x$ belongs $V$ then $Tx = w$ if and only if $x = v + k$ with $k$ in $\operatorname{ker}(T)$.

I can't solve this, someone can help me please.

Comment: yes sorry i edited

Comment: For $\Longrightarrow$) observe $T(x-v)=Tx+T(-v)=Tx+(-Tv)=w+(-w)=0_W$ then $x-v\in\ker T$.

Comment: For $\Longleftarrow$), $k\in \ker(T)\Longrightarrow T(v+k)=Tv+Tk=w+0_W=w$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We are given that $T:V\to W$ is linear with $T(v)=w$.

First, suppose that $T(x)=w$. Then
$$
T(x-v)=T(x)-T(v)=w-w=\mathbf 0
$$
so that $x-v\in\ker T$. That is, there exists a $k\in\ker T$ such that $x-v=k$. Hence $x=v+k$ as required.

Conversely, suppose that $x=v+k$ where $k\in\ker T$. Then
$$
T(x)=T(v+k)
$$
Can you manipulate this equation to conclude that $T(x)=w$?